# isomorphic-fetch (npm) failed in isomorphic, only return "pending" promise

Tags: node.js, redux, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to turn my React app into isomorphic app, everything seems fine, and very strange thing happen.

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
import request from 'axios';
```

The following case failed because the `isomorphic-fetch` return only "pending" promised

```
export function fetchPosts() {
    return {
        type:    RECEIVE_POSTS,
        promise: fetch(POSTS_URL + '?_embed=comments')
    }
}
```

The following case passed because the `axios` return data back

```
export function fetchPosts() {
    return {
        type:    RECEIVE_POSTS,
        promise: request.get(POSTS_URL + '?_embed=comments')
    }
}
```

Any tips on why that happen will be appreciated :)

Comment: did you use redux-promise or redux-thunk?

Comment: I was using a promiseMiddleWare  ( which is very similar to redux-promise )

Comment: R.R. You ever find out what happened?

Comment: @jamesemanon I don't need to use the isomorphic-fetch, and since axios totally works for me, so I don't even bother to look into that further.